# Why doesen't this resize my canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Why doesen't the following code resize my canvas? The id is correct.

```
var canvas;
canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 500;
```

However,this works:

```
var canvas
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 500;
```

Why does creating a new canvas work but getting a already made canvas by ID Not work?

HTML Canvas is like so:

```
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="0" height="0"></canvas>
```

Comment: Can we see your markup - any CSS applied to your canvas?

Comment: Only CSS Applied to canvas is a 2px solid black border. @geedubb

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/0y9p926f/ When does your script run (after the markup??)

Comment: My script tag is placed right after the body.

Comment: Any errors in JS console?

Comment: are you sure that the canvas as been loaded in the dom when you try to retrieve it with getElementById('myCanvas')

Comment: 1 Error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of null @geedubb

Comment: @Hacketo That was the problem.thanks for your help!

Comment: You are querying the canvas before it's even existing in DOM. Place your script before `</body>`, or execute on DOM ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing should be fine - just make sure your script runs after the `canvas` is added to the DOM. You should check the console for additional errors.

Here is an example:

**HTML:**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="0" height="0"></canvas>

<script>
   var canvas;
   canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
   alert(canvas.width + " , " + canvas.height);
   canvas.width = 1000;
   canvas.height = 500;
   alert(canvas.width + " , " + canvas.height);
</script>
```

[JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/0y9p926f/2/)